# Highlight text in \mtctitle

Tags: table-of-contents, highlighting, minitoc, colorbox

I would like to produce a title for a table of contents that is highlighted in yellow. However the code

```
   \renewcommand{\mtctitle}{\colorbox{yellow}{Contents}}
```

does not seem to work, instead giving the error message "Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition." I was wondering if there is a way that I can achieve this effect.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal working document (or that one that shows this error. Remove all unnecessary packages! Have you used `\usepackage{xcolor}` or `\usepackage{color}` at all?

Comment: A look into `minitoc` documentation reveals that `\mtctitle` is meant to contain a mere name, not complicated setup with `\colorbox` etc.

Comment: But how can I have a highlighted contents title?

Comment: This needs some investigation into the `minitoc` package code, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `\mtctitle` to anything but some easy 'string' is not the correct way. `\mtctitle` should contain the real name of the title and not additional fancy typesetting and decorations ;-)

The relevant code where the `minitoc` title is set is in `\minitoc@`, within a `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\columnwidth}@{}}
    \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
```

The code with `\mtctitle` must be replaced by the code having the `colorbox`, this can't be done easily without patching the code.

However, in later parts of `minitoc`, actually `\sv@minitoc@` is used by a `\let\sv@minitoc@\minitoc@` statement, so `\sv@minitoc@` has to be patched actually.

For sake of nicer appearance, I used `tcolorbox` instead of `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\mtctitlebox}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners,halign=left,left=1ex,nobeforeafter,boxrule=0pt]\mtctitle\end{tcolorbox}}


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\sv@minitoc@}{%
  \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitle}\\\hline
}{%  
  \reset@font\mtifont\do@mtitc{\mtc@v\mtctitlebox}\\\hline}{%
  \typeout{success}%
}{%
  \typeout{failure}%
}
\makeatother

\dominitoc



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\minitoc

\section{Foo section}
\end{document}
```

[image]